# Proof verification for bounded sets.

Tags: proof-verification

Is my proof for set boundedness correct?

***Proposition***:

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}.$ Then $A$ is bounded if and only if $\exists{K}\gt{0}$ s.t $\forall{a}\in{A}, |a|\leq{K}$.

***Proof***:

Suppose that $A$ is bounded. Then there exists $M\in \mathbb{R}$ and $m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $m\leq{a}\leq{M}$. Take $K=\text{max}(|M|,|m|,1)$ so that $K\gt{0}$. Therefore $-K\le{a}\le{K}$ and thus,  $|a|\le{K}$.

Conversely, assume that $\exists{K}\gt{0}$ s.t $\forall{a}\in{A}, |a|\leq{K}$ holds. Then we have that $-K\leq{a}\leq{K}$. Therefore $-K\leq{a}$ for all $a\in{A}$ so $A$ is bounded below and $a\leq{K}$
 for all $a\in{A}$ so $A$ is bounded above. Thus, $A$ is bounded.

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: Approved. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks to you both ;)